# jQuery datepicker with German format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to change jQuery datepicker formatting from `MM/DD/YYYY` to German style like `d MMMM yyyy`.

I have tried this code but it does not work with me.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () { 
       $('.datepicker').datepicker(); 
       $(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd-MMMM-yyyy });
     });
  </script>
```

The date format shows like this and never change!

[image]

What is wrong in my code any idea?
thanks

Comment: german style??? DD.MM.YY(YY) , and you may close the string with another '

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        $(".datepicker").datepicker(); 
        $(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy"});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried the code but the date format keep the same the photo that i have just uploaded!

Comment: Your classselector could be wrong or could be returning a collection of elements. It is a better idea to use id and make sure it is correct

Answer (score 0):

German date format is `dd.mm.yyyy` you can use like this

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.selector').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    } 
  );
});
</script>
```